# Some time App take iphone XIB to load controller

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xib

I am creating an application using Apple's new swift language.

Application is universal, so that I created XIB with '~' operator. Like **"MyView~iphone.xib"**  and **MyView~ipad.xib"** . But sometimes, even when my application is running in iPad it loads iPhone nib.

I have tried lots of option but still facing the same issue.

People may think this never happens but I am facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to see the code but i guess your solution is like this

```
BOOL isPad = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
UIViewController *myViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:isPad?@"MyView~ipad.xib":@"MyView~iphone.xib" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: I know this solution. I want to find the reason for this weird behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Hey try using size classes in Interface Builder and you won't need different xibs for both iPhone and iPad. You can take advantage of size classes and setting constraints in storyboard for each of the size class. I recommend you watching [WWDC 2014: Session 216](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#216).

Answer (score 0):

I have had an issue like this objective C but that was way back in iOS 6, I don't know whether this could fix your issue but

Try renaming the files as

```
MyView~iphone.xib for iPhone
MyView.xib for iPad
```

Instead of

```
MyView~iphone.xib
MyView~ipad.xib
```

I would advise you to use Size classes since it is future proof.